# Как сравнить две строки на jquery?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Привет всем. Есть две строки.

```
var s = phonebook/unit/telefony_golovnogo_ofisa;
    var s2 = telefony_golovnogo_ofisa
```

Мне нужно, чтобы

```
if (s==s2) {true}
```

Так как конец того Url совпадает, как это сделать ребят?

Comment: jquery_golovnogo_mozga

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var s = 'phonebook/unit/telefony_golovnogo_ofisa',
    s2 = 'telefony_golovnogo_ofisa',
regexp = new RegExp('\/' + s2 + '$');
if (regexp.test(s)) {
     alert('ok');
}
```

Comment: @kolpak, а если во второй строке будет что-нибудь забавное типа `.*`?

Comment: @Etki, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446170/escape-string-for-use-in-javascript-regex

Comment: @kolpak, вообще это был намек. Не нужно сравнивать регулярками то, что нужно сравнить на точное соответствие.

Comment: @Etki, что тебе мешает предложить своё решение? :)

Comment: @kolpak,

    console.log(s.indexOf(s2) != -1);

Comment: @kolpak, пушо лучше исправлять существующее, чем писать новое. Но раз уж такой запрос поступил.

Comment: @Deonis, ты предлагаешь проверку на вхождение, а не нахождение в конце

Comment: @kolpak, уговорили:

    console.log( (s.indexOf(s2) + s2.length) == s.length );

Comment: @Deonis ага, это и имел ввиду @Etki

Answer (score 1):

```
function testSuffixMatch(stringA, stringB) {
    var buffer;
    if (stringB.length > stringA.length) {
        buffer = stringB;
        stringB = stringA;
        stringA = buffer;
    }
    return stringA.indexOf(stringB) === stringA.length - stringB.length;
}
```

Comment: Достаточно просто

    return stringA.indexOf(stringB, stringA.length - stringB.length) !== -1